# Export CSV from a Google Spreadsheet page from command-line

Tags: google-sheets, automation, linux

I'm using a Google Spreadsheet document to configure a data-driven program.

The program consumes a CSV file, which now I have to export manually from the document. It is rather inconvenient, as everything else is automated.

I'd like to export the CSV file using a bash-script.

How do I do that?

Comment: That's unknown territory for me, but also on SO and the internet.

Comment: There is `googlecl` project that seems to be doing something like what I need, but that still needs more research.

Comment: Perhaps this is of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10860134/1536038

Answer (score 3):

Doing it from bash is very straightforward. All you need to do is run:

```
curl -s -d /dev/null https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/DOCUMENT_ID/export?exportFormat=csv > mydocument.csv
dos2unix mydocument.csv 2> /dev/null
```

This only works for publicly shared documents though. To have access to private documents you will need to use OAuth2. You can find information about doing that [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps) and then you can Google how to use OAuth2 with curl. (Because for the time being I can only post 1 URL at a time)